# Filter by tag after find_all in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to retrieve some info from some tables in a webpage. To do this I´m using the `find_all` method from Beautifulsoup. The thing is that I need to get some text before each table which is under the `h2` tag. That's why I'm using `soup.find_all(['table','h2'])` but I don't know how to retrieve the tag from the result (to determine if it´s a header or a table). I want something along this lines:

```
for tr in soup.find_all(['table','h2']):
            if tr.tag='table':
                print("table info")
            elif tr.tag='h2':
                print("header info")
```

Comment: Let me guess - a wiki page?..

Comment: A website someone made at my workplace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, use [`.find_previous_sibling()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-previous-siblings-and-find-previous-sibling) to get to the previous `h2` element of each `table` element:

```
for table in soup.find_all('table'): 
    header = table.find_previous_sibling("h2").get_text()
    print(header)
```